# i want make this script to be ternary operators

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ternary-operator

```
function checkAnswers() {
  let score = 0;

  if (options1.value == 'correct') {
    score++;
    options1.style.backgroundColor = 'lightGreen';
  } else {
    options1.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
  }

  if (options2.value == 'correct') {
    score++
    options2.style.backgroundColor = 'lightGreen';
  } else {
    options2.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
  }

  if (options3.value == 'correct') {
    score++
    options3.style.backgroundColor = 'lightGreen';
  } else {
    options3.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
  }
  alert(`your score is ${score}`)
}

checkButton.onclick = checkAnswers;
```

I want to make this script to be ternary, how do I do that? I have tried to put code like this below :

```
function checkAnswers() {
    options1.value == "correct" ? score++;
    options1.style.backgroundColor = 'lightGreen': options1.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';

    options2.value == "correct" ? score++;
    options2.style.backgroundColor = 'lightGreen': options2.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';

    options3.value == "correct" ? score++;
    options3.style.backgroundColor = 'lightGreen': options3.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';

}

checkButton.onclick = checkAnswers;
```

Is that possible if we could make the first code on above to be ternary operator, become shorter?

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, while programming, prefer readability over shortness. In the long run, ditching the ternaries will help you and your fellow programmers to understand what you meant.

Comment: The primary intention of of the ternary operator is to be used as expressions - which return something.

Comment: A much better technique would be to create some CSS classes `.option-correct { background-color: lightGreen }` etc. then the code can become `options1.className = 'option-' + options1.value;` and so on with no conditionals whatsoever.

Comment: @Duncan - Completely agreed about using classes. You still need to determine the `score`, though, which involves conditions (in an `if` or conditional operator).

Comment: @Duncan  this is the file of the code,  https://pastebin.com/WczMr8UG, can u give me an example, and correct it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's **possible** to do it, yes, through the comma operator:

```
options1.style.backgroundColor = options1.value == "correct" ? (score++, 'lightGreen') : 'pink';
```

The comma operator is fairly unusual: It evaluates its left-hand operand, then its right-hand operand, and results in the value resulting from its right-hand operand. So you can use the left-hand operand for side-effects.

I don't recommend it, but it's possible.

Instead, though, rather than repeating yourself and writing difficult-to-maintain code with the comma operator, perhaps create a reusable, clear, easy-to-read function:

```
function handleOption(option) {
    if (option.value === 'correct') {
        option.style.backgroundColor = 'lightGreen';
        return 1;
    } else {
        options.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
        return 0;
    }
}
```

or similar. Then `checkAnswers` could be:

```
function checkAnswers() {
    let score = handleOption(option1) +
                handleOption(option2) +
                handleOption(option3);
    alert(`your score is ${score}`)
}
```

or even:

```
function checkAnswers() {
    let score = [option1, option2, option3].reduce(
        (score, option) => score + handleOption(option),
        0
    );
    alert(`your score is ${score}`)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get rid of all of your `if` statements and replace them with the conditional operator, you'll have to use the ugly and hard-to-read comma operator so as to do both `score++` and assign to `backgroundColor` in a single expression, in the first fork:

```
function checkAnswers() {
  options1.style.backgroundColor = option.value === 'correct'
    ? ( score++, 'lightGreen')
    : 'pink';
  options2.style.backgroundColor = option.value === 'correct'
    ? ( score++, 'lightGreen')
    : 'pink';
  options3.style.backgroundColor = option.value === 'correct'
    ? ( score++, 'lightGreen')
    : 'pink';
}
```

Or, to condense it even more, iterate over an array of the `options`:

```
function checkAnswers() {
  [options1, options2, options3].forEach((option) => {
    option.style.backgroundColor = option.value === 'correct'
      ? ( score++, 'lightGreen')
      : 'pink';
  });
}
```

That said, I wouldn't recommend it, because it requires the comma operator, which can easily confuse readers of the code. IMO, better to go with `if`/`else`.